# cancel bootstrap tab click if validation fails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have some bootstrap tabs and if the user clicks one I want to first validate the current pane, if it fails validation I want to cancel the switch to the new tab pane.

I added an onclick handler to the tab anchor and from it I see the tab has not yet changed, I want to now prevent the change.

I tried e.preventDefault() and returning false, but the tab is still changed.

```js
function noteTabClick(e,el) {
    debugger;
    console.log("note tab click");
    console.log(el.href);
    var targetId =  el.href.substr(  el.href.indexOf("#"));
    console.log(targetId);
    //var target  = $(targetId);
    console.log($(targetId).hasClass("active"));
    console.log($("#profile").hasClass("active"));

  //do something

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs tabs-inline tabs-top">
 <li class='active'>
  <a href="#profile" data-toggle='tab'>
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#notes" onclick="noteTabClick(event, this);" data-toggle='tab'>
   <i class="fa fa-sticky-note-o"></i>Notes</a>
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="#events" data-toggle='tab'>
   <i class="fa fa-recycle"></i>Events</a>
 </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content padding tab-content-inline tab-content-bottom">
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
  Profile
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="notes">
  Notes
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane active" id="events">
  Events
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted, only the profile pane is active.

Comment: I have a solution: I removed the tab anchor attribute data-toggle='tab' which by-passes the bootstrap event handler, then in my click handler if valid I toggle the tab manually by removing active from all tabs and tab-panes, then add active to the desired (tragetId) tab and pane.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the e.preventDefault() method to halt the default action of your click.

```
$('.next').on('click',function(e){
    if ($("#form").valid()) {
        $('.nav-item > .active').parent().next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
});
```